# How to detect whether an outgoing call answered or not in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Earlier to Android lollipop detected the outgoing call is answered or not by checking the call duration if the call not answered means the call duration remains 0 Sec. But in Android Lollipop the call duration gets started before call get answered. Is there any way to detect the outgoing call is answered or not in Android lollipop?

Answer (score 0):

You can override onCallStateChanged listener using Telephony Manager.

```
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String number) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // call established.
                break;
        }
```

Comment: CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK will get triggered once we click on call button but I need to find whether that call has been answered by another user or not. In below API Level 19 we can find by using call duration but above API 19 the call duration get started once we click on CALL button.

Comment: Finally got solution for the above issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79592.  In android 5.1 the call duration is working fine for the out going calls.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution to detect when an outgoing call is answered! The solution is a little hacky but it works, at least in Samsung S6 with Android 6.0.1. I've also tested on Nexus 5x with Android 7.1.1 but it didn't work.

The way i do it is using Audio Manager to change the audiomode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION when i get the state of the outgoing call changes to EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK. After changing the  audiomode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, i start a thread that monitors the audiomode until the system changes it back to MODE_IN_CALL when the call is answered.

Here's the code snippet:

```
final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (outgoingCallAnswerWatchThread != null){
    outgoingCallAnswerWatchThread.interrupt();
    outgoingCallAnswerWatchThread = null;
}

outgoingCallAnswerWatchThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // by changing the audio mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
        // we can then detect when the call is answered
        // because android changes the audio mode back to MODE_IN_CALL
        // when that happens
        audioManager.setMode(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

        while(callState == RINGING && !Thread.interrupted()){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(CALL_WATCHER_SLEEP_TIME_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted!");
                break;
            }


            int audioMode = audioManager.getMode();

            Log.d(TAG, "audioMode:" + audioMode);

            if (audioMode == MODE_IN_CALL){
                //the call is connected
                Log.i(TAG, "OUTGOING CALL answered!");
            }

        }

    }
});


outgoingCallAnswerWatchThread.start();
```